# display json from two tables in sql

Tags: php, json

Ive managed to do a simple join statement in sql to query the tables i want correctly but i am having trouble ouputting in json. I keep getting the output [] which to me looks like an empty array.

```
$date_1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["date_1"]);
$date_2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["date_2"]);
$sport_type = ucfirst("$sport_type");
$sport_type = "Cycling - ".$sport_type;


$date1=explode('/',$date_1);
$d = $date1[0];
$m = $date1[1];
$y = $date1[2];
$date1_string = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d; 

$date2=explode('/',$date_2);
$d = $date2[0];
$m = $date2[1];
$y = $date2[2];
$date2_string = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;  


// sql query to display info from database

$sql = "SELECT name, Cyclist.ISO_id, country_name, gdp, population  From Cyclist INNER JOIN Country ON Cyclist.ISO_id=Country.ISO_id WHERE dob BETWEEN $date1_string AND $date2_string ";


$res =& $db->query($sql);
$list = json_encode($res->fetchAll());

if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
    die($res->getMessage());
}
?>

<?php
echo $list
?>
```

where am i going wrong?

Comment: Maybe there's some fault quotes on `BETWEEN` statement on your SQL.

Comment: Ive checked the sql query directly on the database and it gives me the correct results so I do not think that is the problem

Comment: Can you post `$res->fetchAll()` dump?

Comment: tbh I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL date field is in the format YYYY-MM-DD not DD-MM-YYY as you are trying.

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: so ive changed the order around but still no progress

Comment: Can you print out your vars at runtime and also show us your table structure?